# Resposta parecida com a minha postada pouco antes

Tags: suporte, respostas

Se eu posto uma resposta e aparece uma resposta parecida, publicada alguns segundos **antes** devo deletar a minha ou não?

Comment: Não precisa se o intervalo for muito curto. Já vi 4 [respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97711/91) no mesmo minuto

Comment: @rray Lembro desse dia! kkk

Comment: Se forem muito iguais você pode apagar por uma questão de "higiene". Contudo, minha sugestão é sempre se esforçar para ter um *tchan* a mais na sua resposta e assim diferenciá-la das outras.

Comment: Legal obrigado pessoal!

Comment: As pessoas tem o direito de pensar igual, o problema é querer negativas as outras para das destaque a sua.

Comment: Advogado do diabo: as pessoas tem direito de pensar diferente também. É injusto, ultrajante e completamente sem sentido fazer isso, mas não tem nenhuma regra escrita nem nada pode ser feito {1} por moderadores ou *community managers* se alguém quiser fazer "negativação tática" para dar destaque a sua resposta. . . . {1} se virar vicio e for óbvio, talvez algo possa ser feito, sim.

Comment: @brasofilo Casos em que alguém tem a mania de votar contra todas as outras respostas numa pergunta são mais difíceis de acontecer **e** de identificar, mas não é algo que gostamos de ver no site..

Comment: @Gabe, pois sim, está claro que é uma tática vil e que, se a pessoa for descoberta, "bons olhos" não será exatamente o que vai receber da comunidade. Isso dito, já usei a tática uma vez, concorrendo a uma recompensa grande no SOen, sinto um pouquinho de culpa por ter feito, mas também não me arrependo.

Comment: Não entendi. Como pode aparecer uma resposta "segundos antes" depois da sua? Cronologicamente isso é impossível! :)

Comment: @DvD o sistema detecta respostas novas enquanto você esta escrevendo a sua. Obs: essa pergunta é 2015 e ela só veio para o topo (primeira página), porque o usuário Stormwind editou a resposta do utluiz, claro que novas respostas podem ser uteis, mas primeiro é necessário entender um pouco mais a comunidade em certos aspectos que talvez ainda seja um pouco dificil para quem não participa tanto do Meta e certas situações do site principal.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tô ligado. Valeu!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Casos como esse são comuns, principalmente quando a resposta é simples.

Se o conteúdo for exatamente igual você pode apagar por uma questão de *higiene*, isto é, evitar redundância desnecessária e deixar a pergunta mais *arrumadinha*.

Contudo, minha sugestão é sempre se esforçar para dar um *tchan* a mais na sua resposta e assim diferenciá-la das outras. Isso pode ser feito adicionando informações mais precisas, exemplos e alternativas.

Finalmente, como foi colocado perfeitamente pelo Guilherme nos comentários:

> O problema é querer negativas as outras para dar destaque a sua.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que não deve deletar não. A não ser que haja algum critério no site de que "*em caso de respostas iguais, a que foi postada antes (no caso, segundos) deve ter preferência sobre a outra*". Mas isso não acontece. O AP irá marcar a que ele quiser, mesmo que, muita das vezes, ele acaba marcando a mais antiga.

Deixa o AP marcar qual resposta "correta" e, caso não tenha marcado a sua, aí sim acho válido se pensar em excluir a sua, já que a outra foi parecida e a sua não irá acrescentar nada, a não ser que, como falou o @utluiz: mesmo que tecnicamente as respostas sejam parecidas, dar um *tchan* diferente pode ser interessante (colocar uma explicação, um link para mais detalhes etc). Aí você não deve deletar a sua resposta, porque ela irá fornecer mais informações à pergunta, um *plus* a mais além da solução, podendo ajudar futuras pessoas que possam estar procurando solução parecida.