# Que tipo de sinalização fazer quando uma resposta é uma cópia directa de outra?

Tags: debate, suporte

Estava a ver esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122506/como-trabalhar-com-%C3%ADndice-no-thymeleaf#246527) e dei conta que é tal e qual a esta já [respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122506/como-trabalhar-com-%C3%ADndice-no-thymeleaf/122515#122515) este tipo de resposta deve ser assinala? Se sim qual a opção correta para sinalizar: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resposta é errada? não responde a pergunta?

Comment: responde mas já foi usada por outro utilizador deve ser feita alguma coisa nestes casos?

Comment: Creio que a primeira resposta está meio vaga não concordam ? Tipo só está o código e não tem nada de explicação.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza concordo mas no entanto, também não deixa de ser uma repetição. A minha questão aqui é mais o que deve ser feito nestes casos de respostas iguais se alguma coisa ou nada.

Comment: Por esse lado, na minha opnião seria *Span*.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza, se eu for analisar aquilo como spam nas listas de análise rejeitava logo, porque lá não diz que ela é igual a outra, apenas mostra a resposta. e vendo a resposta apenas não é spam. Concordas?

Comment: **:)** Concordo.

Comment: Nenhuma sinalização para este caso. Se a resposta está identica a outra, e não há nada de adicional que torne ela mais completa, sua "arma" é o negativo. Uma resposta ruim não necessariamente precisa ser sinalizada e excluida. Se a outra responde a pergunta, essa tambem, então é uma resposta, apesar de ruim(partindo do ponto de vista de que ela foi postada identica a outra, talvez por desatenção do autor). Outra atitude que pode fazer é comentar questionando o autor de que a resposta já foi dada e que ele possa complementa-la com alguma informação adicional.

Comment: Relacionado: [Resposta parecida com a minha postada pouco antes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4566/3117)

Comment: @Articuno obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: @Math obrigado pela informação

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta não é duplicada — ainda demorei um bocado, mas vi a diferença. A primeira reposta tem lá uma parte assim:

```
<input type="text" th:name="'preco['${status.index}'].valor'">
```

E a mais recente tem lá a mesma parte (a a linha abaixo, com a mesma alteração) assim:

```
<input type="text" th:name="'preco['+${status.index}+'].valor'">
```

Reparem que a mais recente tem uns +s a mais, que estam lá para responder [à última das revisões da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/122506/5) — portanto, antes de pensarmos em sinalizar seja o que for, lembrem-se **que é importante analisar a resposta no contexto *temporal* da pergunta, e de quaisquer outras actualizações que tenham havido no resto do post** (comentários, etc.).

*Se*, depois disso, virem que a resposta é mesmo igual a outra existente, devem sinalizá-la com a opção "precisa de atenção dos moderadores" e possivelmente deixar um comentário que aponte o autor para [este artigo da central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) — fazer isto pode ser o suficiente para este ver que havia lá outra respota idêntica, caso não tenha reparado; mas também o aponta para o artigo caso a utilização de código presente noutras respostas seja proposidato, e apenas mal citado.

Comment: Também reparei que não são idênticas, mas parecidas... Se fosse um `CTRL+C` e `CTRL+V` do código, talvez algo poderia ser feito. Talvez ele poderia ter editado a resposta antiga para arrumar esse detalhe ao invés de criar uma nova resposta parecida, por exemplo, não sei...